# 404 error page configuration with Spring 4 annotations

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlet-3.0

I have a Spring MVC project with Spring 4. My server is tomcat 7.
I'm trying to make a 404 page, I tried many things, but I couldn't do that.

What am I missing?

Here is WebAppContext :

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {
        "com.***"
})
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebAppContext extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String VIEW_RESOLVER_PREFIX = "/WEB-INF/pages/";
    private static final String VIEW_RESOLVER_SUFFIX = ".jsp";

    @Autowired
    private EventLogService eventLogService;

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleMappingExceptionResolver exceptionResolver() {
        SimpleMappingExceptionResolver exceptionResolver = new SimpleMappingExceptionResolver();

        Properties exceptionMappings = new Properties();
        exceptionMappings.put("org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.CookieTheftException", "user/login?error=sessionExpired");
        exceptionMappings.put("java.lang.RuntimeException", "error/error");
        exceptionMappings.put("java.lang.Exception", "error/error");
        exceptionResolver.setExceptionMappings(exceptionMappings);

        Properties statusCodes = new Properties();
        statusCodes.put("error/403", "403");
        statusCodes.put("error/404", "404");
        statusCodes.put("error/error", "500");
        exceptionResolver.setStatusCodes(statusCodes);

        return exceptionResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();

        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix(VIEW_RESOLVER_PREFIX);
        viewResolver.setSuffix(VIEW_RESOLVER_SUFFIX);

        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor());
        registry.addInterceptor(new EventLogInterceptor(eventLogService)).addPathPatterns("/xyz/{urlText}");
    }

    @Bean 
    public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor(){
        LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor=new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
        localeChangeInterceptor.setParamName("lang");
        return localeChangeInterceptor;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        CookieLocaleResolver cookieLocaleResolver = new CookieLocaleResolver();
        cookieLocaleResolver.setDefaultLocale(new Locale("en"));
        return cookieLocaleResolver;
    }

}
```

Here is my security config

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            //Configures form login
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login/authenticate")
                .failureUrl("/login?error=bad_credentials")
            .and()
                .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403")
            //Configures the logout function
            .and()
                .logout()
                    .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                    .logoutUrl("/logout")
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
            //Configures url based authorization
            .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    //Anyone can access the urls
                    .antMatchers(
                            "/auth/**",
                            "/signin",
                            "/login",
                            "/feedback",
                            "/signup/**",
                            "/user/forgotPass/**"
                    ).permitAll()
                    .antMatchers(
                            "/user/settings/**"
                            ).authenticated()
                    .antMatchers(
                            "/report/**"
                    ).hasAnyRole("ADMIN")
                    .antMatchers("/manage/**"
                    ).hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "EDITOR")
            .and()
                    .rememberMe().rememberMeServices(springSocialSecurityRememberMeServices())
                    .key("MyRememberMe")
            .and()
                .apply(new SpringSocialConfigurer());
}
```

Application Config:

```
public class ApplicationConfig implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    private static final String DISPATCHER_SERVLET_NAME = "dispatcher";
    private static final String DISPATCHER_SERVLET_MAPPING = "/";

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        rootContext.register(ApplicationContext.class);

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet(DISPATCHER_SERVLET_NAME, new DispatcherServlet(rootContext));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping(DISPATCHER_SERVLET_MAPPING);

        EnumSet<DispatcherType> dispatcherTypes = EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST, DispatcherType.FORWARD);

        CharacterEncodingFilter characterEncodingFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
        characterEncodingFilter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        characterEncodingFilter.setForceEncoding(true);

        FilterRegistration.Dynamic characterEncoding = servletContext.addFilter("characterEncoding", characterEncodingFilter);
        characterEncoding.addMappingForUrlPatterns(dispatcherTypes, true, "/*");

        FilterRegistration.Dynamic security = servletContext.addFilter("springSecurityFilterChain", new DelegatingFilterProxy());
        security.addMappingForUrlPatterns(dispatcherTypes, true, "/*");

        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));
    }
}
```

My page is at `/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/pages/error/404.jsp` location.

I get this error page, when I try a random url:
[image]

Here is the log file:

```
2015-09-01 09:25:05 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /test at position 1 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2015-09-01 09:25:05 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /test at position 2 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2015-09-01 09:25:05 DEBUG HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository:167 - Obtained a valid SecurityContext from SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT: 'org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@44339553: Authentication: org.springframework.security.authentication.RememberMeAuthenticationToken@44339553: Principal: com.**@2e96279e[id=10,username=**,firstName=**,lastName=**,role=ROLE_USER,socialSignInProvider=<null>,profileImageUrl;=<null>]; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER'
2015-09-01 09:25:05 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /test at position 3 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2015-09-01 09:25:05 DEBUG HstsHeaderWriter:129 - Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@a3c01f
2015-09-01 09:25:05 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /test at position 4 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CsrfFilter'
2015-09-01 09:25:05 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /test at position 5 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
2015-09-01 09:25:05 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:145 - Checking match of request : '/test'; against '/logout'
2015-09-01 09:25:05 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /test at position 6 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SocialAuthenticationFilter'
2015-09-01 09:25:05 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /test at position 7 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
2015-09-01 09:25:05 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:127 - Request 'GET /test' doesn't match 'POST /login/authenticate
2015-09-01 09:25:05 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /test at position 8 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
2015-09-01 09:25:05 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /test at position 9 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
2015-09-01 09:25:05 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /test at position 10 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RememberMeAuthenticationFilter'
2015-09-01 09:25:05 DEBUG RememberMeAuthenticationFilter:142 - SecurityContextHolder not populated with remember-me token, as it already contained: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.RememberMeAuthenticationToken@44339553: Principal: com.**@2e96279e[id=10,username=**,firstName=**,lastName=**,role=ROLE_USER,socialSignInProvider=<null>,profileImageUrl;=<null>]; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER'
2015-09-01 09:25:05 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /test at position 11 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
2015-09-01 09:25:05 DEBUG AnonymousAuthenticationFilter:107 - SecurityContextHolder not populated with anonymous token, as it already contained: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.RememberMeAuthenticationToken@44339553: Principal: com.**@2e96279e[id=10,username=**,firstName=**,lastName=**,role=ROLE_USER,socialSignInProvider=<null>,profileImageUrl;=<null>]; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER'
2015-09-01 09:25:05 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /test at position 12 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
2015-09-01 09:25:05 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /test at position 13 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
2015-09-01 09:25:05 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /test at position 14 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
2015-09-01 09:25:05 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:145 - Checking match of request : '/test'; against '/auth/**'
2015-09-01 09:25:05 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:145 - Checking match of request : '/test'; against '/signin'
2015-09-01 09:25:05 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:145 - Checking match of request : '/test'; against '/login'
2015-09-01 09:25:05 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:145 - Checking match of request : '/test'; against '/feedback'
2015-09-01 09:25:05 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:145 - Checking match of request : '/test'; against '/signup/**'
2015-09-01 09:25:05 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:145 - Checking match of request : '/test'; against '/user/forgotpass/**'
2015-09-01 09:25:05 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:145 - Checking match of request : '/test'; against '/user/activate/**'
2015-09-01 09:25:05 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:145 - Checking match of request : '/test'; against '/user/register/**'
2015-09-01 09:25:05 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:145 - Checking match of request : '/test'; against '/user/{username}/**'
2015-09-01 09:25:05 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:145 - Checking match of request : '/test'; against '/user/settings/**'
2015-09-01 09:25:05 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:145 - Checking match of request : '/test'; against '/report/**'
2015-09-01 09:25:05 DEBUG FilterSecurityInterceptor:185 - Public object - authentication not attempted
2015-09-01 09:25:05 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:323 - /test reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
2015-09-01 09:25:05 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:845 - DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher' processing GET request for [/test]
2015-09-01 09:25:05 DEBUG RequestMappingHandlerMapping:297 - Looking up handler method for path /test
2015-09-01 09:25:05 DEBUG RequestMappingHandlerMapping:305 - Did not find handler method for [/test]
2015-09-01 09:25:05 DEBUG SimpleUrlHandlerMapping:169 - Matching patterns for request [/test] are [/**]
2015-09-01 09:25:05 DEBUG SimpleUrlHandlerMapping:194 - URI Template variables for request [/test] are {}
2015-09-01 09:25:05 DEBUG SimpleUrlHandlerMapping:124 - Mapping [/test] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler@3396f11f] and 1 interceptor
2015-09-01 09:25:05 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:931 - Last-Modified value for [/test] is: -1
2015-09-01 09:25:05 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:1018 - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
2015-09-01 09:25:05 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:991 - Successfully completed request
2015-09-01 09:25:05 DEBUG ExceptionTranslationFilter:115 - Chain processed normally
2015-09-01 09:25:05 DEBUG SecurityContextPersistenceFilter:97 - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

Comment: is your spring app bound to `/`, or why are random urls expected to work? What you define in your spring app applies only to your spring app context, which is usually something like `/yourapp`.

Comment: My application context is `/`. I test the url by `http://localhost:8081/test`

Comment: Ok, then it makes sense. Is there some reason you're not doing `<error-page><error-code>404</error-code> <location>/404</location> </error-page>` using web.xml?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This issue is related to `Servlet 3` spec rather than `Spring MVC 4`. Although Servlet 3 provided a programatic mechanism to configure the web components (Servlets, Filters etc.), it is still not full fledged. There is a JIRA which explains this https://java.net/jira/browse/SERVLET_SPEC-50.

So, the solution is to add `web.xml` and configure error pages there in traditional way.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">
    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/WEB-INF/pages/error/404.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
</web-app>
```

Comment: you'll want to add `<error-code>` in the example as well, as http status 404 is the needed one.

Comment: @eis, you are correct. I have updated the answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: My problem is I don't have a web.xml. And I don't know how to add this by java based configuration. I added my `ApplicationConfig ` class

Comment: @fyelci this answer just explained that you cannot do that with java based configuration due to servlet 3.0 limitations - you'll need to add web.xml to your project.

Comment: @fyelci, I understand you don't have `web.xml`. My suggestion was to add one. If your project is Maven based, add it under `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/` (the idea is to put it under regular WEB-INF folder). Rebuild your application and deploy. For the content, copy from my answer. It should work.