# Handling exceptions in JavaEE without web.xml

Tags: java, exception, jakarta-ee, annotations

Is there a way to map exception handling to a servlet or JSP without adding options into web.xml? How I understand starting from Java Servlets 3.0 all should be possible without web.xml.

I'm about this kind of options

```
<error-page>
  <exception-type>java.lang.RuntimeException</exception-type>
  <location>/WEB-INF/jsps/exception.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

Comment: An old answer, but back in 2015 (with Servlets 3.0) error pages were apparently not covered yet: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32325013/14955  Maybe this has been fixed now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the current API requires you to put `error-page` in your *web.xml* for custom error handling. `Servlet 3.0` is a step in the right direction, but it is not a fully-fledged replacement and you can't do everything you'd like to with annotations alone. Error pages are one of it's limitations.

The most modern & minimal approach is to define a servlet resposible for handling your errors. *See below.*

**web.xml**

```
<error-page> 
    <exception-type>java.lang.RuntimeException</exception-type> 
    <location>/runtimeErrorHandler</location> 
</error-page>
```

**RuntimeErrorHandlerServlet.java**

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/runtimeErrorHandler")
public class RuntimeErrorHandlerServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
        resp.setContentType("text/html; charset=utf-8");
        try (PrintWriter writer = resp.getWriter()) {
            // Write your error handling page here...
        }
    }

}
```

*Note that you should not be catching such broad exception types. Instead, you should handle the specific types you are concerned with.*

Comment: And what's about Servlet 4.0?

Comment: The details of error handling in Servlet 4.0 can be found [here](https://javaee.github.io/servlet-spec/downloads/servlet-4.0/servlet-4_0_FINAL.pdf) but in summary, the same restrictions still apply.